# How to retrieve the selected choice from a dropdown menu from a sqlite list using Flask, sqlalchemy and HTML

Tags: python, html, flask-sqlalchemy

I am very new to Flask, SQL and Html integration.  This is done for the fun of learning something new only.  I am self taught so my code is def beginner level.
I have searched similar posts, but after spending days on this i now need some help.

I have a project utilising SQLlite, FLask and Html.  I am wanting to pull through data from SQL - which i can do, then either  display it in another page, open within the same page, show further information based on the selection etc as required..

However, the issue is that I cannot get(utilise, print out on screen etc) the selected person from a drop down list - no matter what i try.

I can pull through a drop down list which retrieves a list of users from my students table and is shown in html. (see below)

[drop down list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1ck4.png)

my database has a table called students. 2 of the fields are username, surname
I can access sqlite fine and pull through query without an issue.

some of my code from **app.py**

```
def Teachers_ht():
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Handles my form submission
        return submit()
    else:
        # shows the page with student names again
        return students_list()


def students_list():
    try:
        # Retrieve all student names from the database
        student_names = Students.query.with_entities(Students.firstname, Students.surname).all()
        if not student_names:
            error_message = "No students found in the database."
            return render_template('500.html', error_message=error_message), 500
        print(student_names)  # Should print the student names to the console for debugging - cannot see anything
        return render_template('teachers.html', student_names=student_names)
    except Exception as e:
        error_message = str(e)  # Get the error message and shows in my 500.html below
        return render_template('500.html', error_message=error_message), 500

def submit():
    selected_student_id = request.form.get('student_id')
    selected_student = None  # placeholder, to ensure variable esits (i think)
    if selected_student_id:
        # Retrieve the selected student from the database
        selected_student = Students.query.get(selected_student_id)
    # Retrieve all students' first names and surnames from the database
    student_names = Students.query.with_entities(Students.firstname, Students.surname).all()
    return render_template('teachers.html', student_names=student_names, selected_student=selected_student)
```

my html: teachers.html

```
    <div id="selected_student_id">
        {% if selected_student_id %}
            <h2>Selected Student ID:</h2>
            <p>{{ selected_student_id }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('submit_button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            var form = document.getElementById('student_form');
            var formData = new FormData(form);
    
            // Sends a POST request to the /submit endpoint
            fetch('/submit', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                // Updates the selected student's details section
                var selectedStudentDetails = document.getElementById('selected_student_details');
                selectedStudentDetails.innerHTML = ''; // Clear existing content
                if (data.selected_student) {
                    var h2 = document.createElement('h2');
                    h2.textContent = 'Selected Student Details:';
                    selectedStudentDetails.appendChild(h2);
    
                    var p = document.createElement('p');
                    p.textContent = data.selected_student.firstname + ' ' + data.selected_student.surname;
                    selectedStudentDetails.appendChild(p);
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Hopefully the above is enough, thankyou for looking.

My website does not error, but neither does it do show any output.
I have gone through tutorials and this website.
I have confirmed that i can get and post data within other htmls using a submit box, type in a name and i can retrieve this to the same webpage.

Resolved

I have now resolved this, essentially
in the html it now reads

````
                <div>
                    {{form.student_i(size=1)}} ```

in the forms i have a new class
```class TeachersForm(FlaskForm):
    submit = SubmitField('Enter')
    student_i = SelectField(u'student_i')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TeachersForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        students = Students.query.all()
        choices = [("", "Select a student")]  # Empty option
        # here the student id is hidden from the user, but the firstname and surname are shown
        choices += [(student.studentid, f"{student.firstname} {student.surname}") for student in students]
        self.student_i.choices = choices
````